# how to visualize the effect of a variable in a multiple point process model fitted using gam using spatstat?

Tags: plot, poisson, gam, spatstat, replicate

I am fitting multiple point process model fitted using gam in spatstat (version 3.0-7).
To be clear I am using a call of the general form:

> `mppm(formula, data=hyperframe, eps=0.5, rbord=0.5, use.gam=TRUE)`

Thus my model is Poisson process.

What I would like to do when the model is fitted is to plot:

1. the effect of a given predictor variable in an `mgcv::plot.gam` fashion
2. maps of the spatial trend.

However I get these error messages When trying to use functions

- `effectfun()` : Error: First argument 'model' should be a fitted model of class ‘ppm’, ‘kppm’, ‘lppm’, ‘dppm’, ‘rppm’ or ‘profilepl’
- `plot.mppm()` : Error: This calculation is not supported for GAM fits

I am considering the following workaround options:

**Subfit approach in `spatstat`**

1. re-fit the model to each pattern in my hyperframe individually (because `subfits` does not work for gam): I apply the same model formula used in the `mppm` model and run it in a `ppm` for each pattern. But in doing so, I might modify the `k` parameters independently for each pattern because the k-value used in mppm might give an error with some variables.
2. use `effectfun` and `plot` on each individually fitted ppm models. Here I am afraid that I could possibly end up with splines shapes different for each pattern, thus complication the interpretation

**hack `mppm` and use `mgcv`**

1. run the `mppm` with `use.gam=T` model I want.
2. extract the data.frame from the mppm object using `my_model$Fit$moadf`
3. fit the model with `mgcv::gam` using the call that is used internally by `mppm`:

> `gam(fmla, family = quasi(link = log, variance = mu), weights = .mpl.W * caseweight, data = moadf, subset = (.mpl.SUBSET == "TRUE"), control = ctrl)`

4. at that point, I could use the `mgcv` functions to visualize the plots I need (at least the effect of a given predictor variable.

**My questions**

Is any of my described approaches good? One of them to be preferred? Or, are there other (better) options to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer:* extract the fitted `gam` object directly as

```
m <- my_model$Fit$FIT
```

Then do `plot(m, ...)` which invokes `mgcv::plot.gam`.

*Long answer:*

Currently, `gam` fits (produced when `use.gam=TRUE`) are not fully supported in `mppm`.

Currently we use the `subfits` mechanism to perform many tasks for `mppm` objects, including plotting and predicting the model. This is our way to avoid (for the moment) having to re-write all of the code that supports the `ppm` class, all over again to support the `mppm` class.

The function `subfits` is a hack which involves making "fake" objects of class `ppm` (they are fake because they were not actually obtained by fitting a model to a single point pattern). This fakery has limitations and it does not work at all when the model is fitted by `gam`.

Ultimately the code supporting the `mppm` class will be rewritten as native code and this problem will be resolved. Until then, I suggest you use the approach described in the short answer.

Comment: Thank you! that helps a lot.
Will then be ok to use a similar approach for model validation? I mean, using the mgcv function such as gam.check on the fitted gam object extracted via my_model$Fit$FIT?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Berman-Turner device is just a way to fit the model, exploiting the fact that the likelihood of the point process model has the same form as the likelihood of the GLM or GAM. Other properties of the two models are different, such as the formulas for variance (that is why there is separate code for `vcov.ppm`). So, it is not guaranteed that the output of `gam.check` will be correct when applied to a `gam` object used inside `ppm` or `mppm`.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation. In the light of your previous comment, how can one validate an `mppm` fitted with `gam`? My initial approach was similar to what I called "Subfit approach in spatstat" in my original question. Specifically, fitting one independent gam `ppm` model for each replicated point pattern in the dataset, using the same formula as the `mppm` that I want to validate (and adjusting k values if needed, e.g. in case of errors). Then using `diagnose.ppm`, `parres`, and `qqplot.ppm`  I look their behaviour in each ppm model. Then I judge the mppm on the majority of ppms?